# Modify char variable binary content using C

Tags: c, binary, char

I'm new to C and I need to change the binary content of the char variable using C.

For example,

```
char c = 01011000;
```

Now I want to exchange left 2 bits with right side 2 bits.
Then it should be like this.

01011000 => 00011001

Is there a way to do such a thing?

---

I solved the issue thanks to [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind)

```
unsigned char c =  strtol("10101111", 0, 2);
unsigned char maskLeft,maskRight ,maskMiddle, extractLeft,extractRight,extractMiddle, extractCombi;
unsigned char extractLeft_moved, extractRight_moved;
unsigned char finalResult;

// ~0 = 11111111
maskLeft = ~0 << 6;                     // 11000000
maskRight = ~(~0 << 2);                 // ~(11111100) = 00000011
maskMiddle = ~(maskLeft | maskRight);   // ~(11000011) = 00111100

extractLeft = c & maskLeft;             // 10101111 & 11000000 = 10000000 
extractRight = c & maskRight;           // 10101111 & 00000011 = 00000011
extractMiddle = c & maskMiddle;         // 10101111 & 00111100 = 00101100

// Now move left side 2 bits to right side
extractLeft_moved = extractLeft >> 6;   // 00000010
// Move right side 2 bits to left side
extractRight_moved = extractRight << 6; // 11000000
extractCombi = extractLeft_moved | extractRight_moved; // 11000010

// Combine middle bits with exchange bits
finalResult = extractCombi | extractMiddle; // 00101100 | 11000010 = 11101110
```

Comment: seems like homework?? And Yes, there's always a way!

Comment: Note that there is no standard syntax for binary integers in C; your code uses an octal (base 8) literal since it starts with the digit `0` followed by a digit in the range 0..7.

Comment: Initialize `c` with `strtol("01011000", 0, 2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use bitwise and (`&`) to extract ("mask off") bits of interest, bitwise shift (`<<` and `>>`) to move bits around inside an integer, and bitwise or (`|`) to combine multiple integers together bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = ( ((c & 0X3) << 6) | (c & 0x3c) | ((c & 0xc0) >> 6) ) ;
```

Comment: Can you explain me the meaning of 0X3, 0X4, 0Xc0

Comment: c & 0x3 will extract the last 2 bit from character and  a left shif by 6 will place 2 bit from lsb to msb.

Comment: similarly you can extract the 2 msb bit and placed them at lsb location(c & 0xc0)>>6). c & 0x4c will mast 4 bit(2 lsb and 2 msb) and at te end you are doing a or operator to get the result

Comment: Didn't you mean 0x3c in the middle term?

Comment: yes you are right it should be 0x3c